# Get username for PID (ProcessId)

Tags: powershell, wmi, pid

I have a PID for which I want to check its username. I knew that we can use `GetOwner()`, but it is the valid method for `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process`. I am using `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` in which there is no way to get username (as per I search online). So, I think to check PID separately is the only way to resolve this.

Can you please tell me how can I get the username of PID or get username inside `Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is described in this technet article :[Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/45c541e0-fb49-4ac7-bcaf-738315a70863/getprocess-and-username?forum=winserverpowershell) you can use the code below.

In the last line you can put the process you want after the get-process command.

e.g. `Get-Process outlook | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}`

```
$owners = @{}
gwmi win32_process |% {$owners[$_.handle] = $_.getowner().user}
Get-Process | select processname,Id,@{l="Owner";e={$owners[$_.id.tostring()]}}
```

The time it takes depends on how many services are currently running.
Your output will be like:

```
ProcessName      Id         Owner
-----------      --         -----
OUTLOOK          13128      UserName
```

Hope that helps.
Kind regards.